# pegar todas as chaves em um array de json com js

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho um array de json, que atualmente pego os valores dessa forma:

```
for(element in data){
    data[element]['productor']
}
```

e minha duvida é a seguinte, teria como eu jogar no html, todas as minhas chaves e valores sem necessariamente saber quais são?
se eu tiro o `['productor']` na tela aparece assim `[object Object]`
obrigado

Comment: O que seria a variavel `element`?

Comment: Pelo que percebi, data é um array em que seus elementos sao objetos correto? se possível poste um exemplo do array data. Ai consigo de da uma resposta exata de como resolver. Faço esse tipo de acesso diariamente em meus programas.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o método `keys` da classe `Object` você obtém um *array* contendo todas as chaves do *array* passado. Aí basta efetuar seu loop nessa lista:

```js
//declaro o array "x" e insiro alguns valores
var meuArray = [];
meuArray['a'] = 1;
meuArray['b'] = 2;
meuArray['c'] = 3;
meuArray['d'] = 4;

//array de chaves
var chaves = Object.keys(meuArray);

//loop
for (i of chaves) {
  console.log('exemplo 1:', i, meuArray[i]);
}
```

Utilizando métodos como `forEach`, dá para resumir tudo em uma só cadeia. 
Para jogar no HTML, basta escolher o elemento que conterá os dados e incrementar seu `innerHTML`:

```js
var meuArray = [];
meuArray['a'] = 1;
meuArray['b'] = 2;
meuArray['c'] = 3;
meuArray['d'] = 4;

Object.keys(meuArray).forEach(chave => {
  console.log('exemplo 2:', chave, meuArray[chave]);
  document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML += `Chave ${chave}, valor: ${meuArray[chave]} <br>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"productor":"Bush Chemist","genre":"UK Roots","singer":"Culture Freeman","rpm":"45","name":"King David Style","label":"Conscious Sounds","description":"teste","release_date":"2003","inch":"12"}
```

meu json vem nesse formato, mas ele pode vir isso, menos registros, ou mais registros, precisava pegar a chave e valor dele e colocar no html.
Meu metodo de preencher a tabela recebe o json como parametro

```
function fillTable(data){
for(element in data){
    //resultSet.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data[element]);
    resultSet.innerHTML += `
        <label>${JSON.stringify(data[element])}</label>
    `
}
```

}

que capturo da minha requisição

```
function listAll(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/findAllSource",
    success:function(data){
        fillTable(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
        alert("Error")
        console.log(data);

    }
});
```

}